# How to add classes to some images in a multi value image field?

Tags: media, theming

I have content type with a multi value image field. When adding images is it possible to add a class to some of these images? The mark up I'm trying to achieve is some thing like:

```
<div class="field-item even">
<div class="field-item odd">
<div class="field-item even">
<div class="field-item odd my-class">
<div class="field-item even my-class">
<div class="field-item odd">
```

So when creating a new node I would like to add 'my-class' to come of the images. I've looked as Field Formatter modules but these seem to add the class on all items in the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a tpl.php file for your image field.

```
Possible override templates are:

field.tpl.php
field--field-type.tpl.php
field--field-name.tpl.php
field--content-type.tpl.php
field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php
```

code for field--field-name.tpl.php file as below.

```
 <?php

/**
 * @file field--field-name.tpl.php
 * Default template implementation to display the value of a field.
 *
 * This file is not used and is here as a starting point for customization only.
 * @see theme_field()
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $items: An array of field values. Use render() to output them.
 * - $label: The item label.
 * - $label_hidden: Whether the label display is set to 'hidden'.
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through
 *   CSS. It can be manipulated through the variable $classes_array from
 *   preprocess functions. The default values can be one or more of the
 *   following:
 *   - field: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
 *   - field-name-[field_name]: The current field name. For example, if the
 *     field name is "field_description" it would result in
 *     "field-name-field-description".
 *   - field-type-[field_type]: The current field type. For example, if the
 *     field type is "text" it would result in "field-type-text".
 *   - field-label-[label_display]: The current label position. For example, if
 *     the label position is "above" it would result in "field-label-above".
 *
 * Other variables:
 * - $element['#object']: The entity to which the field is attached.
 * - $element['#view_mode']: View mode, e.g. 'full', 'teaser'...
 * - $element['#field_name']: The field name.
 * - $element['#field_type']: The field type.
 * - $element['#field_language']: The field language.
 * - $element['#field_translatable']: Whether the field is translatable or not.
 * - $element['#label_display']: Position of label display, inline, above, or
 *   hidden.
 * - $field_name_css: The css-compatible field name.
 * - $field_type_css: The css-compatible field type.
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened
 *   into a string within the variable $classes.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_field()
 * @see theme_field()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
?>
<!--
THIS FILE IS NOT USED AND IS HERE AS A STARTING POINT FOR CUSTOMIZATION ONLY.
See http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_field/7 for details.
After copying this file to your theme's folder and customizing it, remove this
HTML comment.
-->
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php $i = 0; ?>        
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?> custom-class-<?php print $i;?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info check [field.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7)

To override node.tpl.php [check](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7)

You can also check this link https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it seems that with this approach I cannot control which images from the multi-value field will have the class applied? This will apply the class to all images or images in a set order. I need to be able to select which images have the class applied as I upload them as the class could be applied in any order or none at all.

Comment: you can add your css in the foreach loop

Comment: <?php $i = 0; ?><?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?> <?php $i++; ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?> customclass-<?php print $i;?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: But this will add it to all field-items? I need to be able to select which field-items have the class when creating a node.

Comment: I have change the code and file name also mention your file name as field--field-name.tpl.php and this you can change class name only for this field for all node. If you want to change the field class for particular content type then create a file like this field--field-name--content-type.tpl.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [field preprocess function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7).  You place it in your theme's `template.php`.  You can make it only fire for specific fields, something like this:

```
    function MY_THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
      $element = $variables['element'];
      if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
        // Test to see if matches your field.
        if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_MY_MULTI_IMAGE_FIELD') { // Add your additional logic here
          $variables['classes_array'][] = 'my-class';
        }
      }
    }
```

(Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7582794/716845)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems like it can work, what I have done is created a file entity for the image field with a text select list. In this select list I have defined 'full-width' and 'half-width' options. Is it possible to output that logic into the above code? So if a image is uploaded and I select 'Half Width' from the options, that class gets applied to the image.

Comment: What happens if you print the value of $variables (if you have the devel module enabled `dpm($variables)`)?  I think the entire node is available there so you could check the setting.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I ended up solving what I needed to do using the Paragraphs module. Rather than adding classes in the template and then positioning with CSS, I set up different Paragraphs bundles to allow site users to display images in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I ended up solving what I needed to do using the Paragraphs module. Rather than adding classes in the template and then positioning with CSS, I set up different Paragraphs bundles to allow site users to display images in different ways.